# Unable to connect to remote SQLServer using 'sa'

Tags: sql-server, go

I'm trying to connect to a remote instance of SQLServer using a connection string for a Go program that I'm writing.

I have a local version of the remote database with the same users.

If I connect to my local DB with a connection string like this, it works just fine:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;User Id=<user>;Password=<password>;
```

Now if I use the same credentials, but I just change the data source, it also works just fine:

```
Data Source=<remoteIP>;Initial Catalog=master;User Id=<user>;Password=<password>;
```

Now if I try and log in using 'sa', it works locally, but not remotely.

This works just fine:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;User Id=sa;Password=<password>;
```

But this does not work:

```
Data Source=<remoteIP>;Initial Catalog=master;User Id=sa;Password=<password>;
```

The error I get when I try to connect to the remote server in my Go program is:

```
Login error: mssql: Login failed for user 'sa'.
```

The really frustrating part is that if I copy and paste the username and password, I can connect to the remote DB in SMSS using that login information, and everything works just fine.

I've double-checked to ensure that the remote 'sa' login allows for both Windows Authentication and SQL Authentication. Is there another setting or something that would prevent me from being able to log in to my remote server using 'sa'?

I'm so puzzled because I clearly can connect to the remote DB if I'm using a different user, but I can't connect using 'sa'.

Are there additional settings I have to configure on the remote server? I'm also a bit frustrated with [this](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb) because I can't print out what the actual error code is. It just tells me that my login failed when I print the error message.

Comment: _Don't do this!_ It's **really poor practice** to use the `sa` account. Create a different account with the permissions you need, including adding/removing databases and altering permissions, if necessary.

Comment: What do the logs in the instance say? (But Joel's point rings very true, you shouldn't be using the `sa` account for anything other than `sa` stuff).

Comment: Not sure what is confusing here. Obviously you don't have the correct password for the sa account, or perhaps the sa account no longer exists. You shouldn't be using sa anyway.

Comment: I do not plan on actually using the ```sa``` account. I'm just trying to figure out why I can't connect to the remote DB using those credentials, but I could locally.
Like I've said, I can connect using another account. But I'm just wondering why I can't connect here.

Comment: But if you aren't going to be using the `sa` account in the future, *why* does it matter? Why fix a broken car that you're going to scrap for the price of metal? It gains nothing apart from wasted time.

Comment: @Larnu Purely for understanding.

Comment: Just to try it out, I've made a new account on the remote DB and I have the same problem. If I try and connect, I get the error saying that ```Login failed for user 'test_user'```. However, if I take the username and password from my connection string, and paste them into SMSS, I can log in without any issues.

Comment: Is the database you are connecting to on the ROOT instance on the server?   Or on a named instance?

Comment: @TabAlleman I'm connecting to the Root instance.

Comment: That error means invalid credentials. There has to be something you are missing here. Maybe it's not the server you think it is. Named instance, maybe some firewall settings that are redirecting IPs to another. This kind of debugging is almost impossible remotely, with no code and no access to anything.

Comment: @SeanLange This was the tip that I needed. I did go back and double-check. It turns out that it was always connecting locally, even if I had the "Data Source" defined.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem.

For the new user that I created (see the original post's comments), it couldn't connect because of my connection string.

I tried first making my connection string the following, which still worked connecting me locally:

```
Initial Catalog=master;User Id=<user>;Password=<password>;
```

I was confused because this still worked, despite me not setting a Data Source.

So what I did was try using "Server", and it worked:

```
Server=<remoteIP>;Initial Catalog=master;User Id=<user>;Password=<password>;
```

So it turns out it was an invalid credential error because it was always trying to connect to my local DB. Thanks for everyone's input.